# Drop item from one sortable list to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two sortable lists that are not connected to each other:

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li>Container 1</li>
    <li>Container 2</li>
    <li>Container 3</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#list1").sortable({
    items: "li",
    distance: 25,
    out: function (event, ui) {},
    over: function (event, ui) {},
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("#list2").sortable({
    items: "li",
    distance: 25,
    out: function (event, ui) {},
    over: function (event, ui) {},
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
});
```

How can I make it possible to drop an item of the first list any item of the second one, and get which one was dropped and where it was dropped?

[**Live jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/enb081/ZVdRW/)

EDIT:I want to create a relation between the elements of the first list to the second. If the user drags an item from the first list and drops it into any item of the second list, I should get one relation (e.g. item1 - container1) and item1 should get back to its place.

Comment: Have you considered using http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ and http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ ?

Comment: Yes, but it messes up the way they get sorted

Comment: `possible to drop an item of the first list any item of the second one` what does ths means ?

Comment: @dreamCoder  
I want to create a relation between the elements of the first list to the second. If the user drags an item from the first list and drops it into any item of the second list, I should get one relation (e.g. item1 - container1) and item1 should get back to its place.

Comment: This is not exactly what you are asking for, but have you ever checked out knockoutjs?  Here's a pretty cool jsFiddle by Ryan Niemeyer. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Jr2rE/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following. It is working fine for me

```
$("#list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '#list2'
});
$("#list2").sortable({
    connectWith: '#list1'
});
```